# How to post array with PHP

Tags: php, post, http-post

i have an array in php

loadHTMLFile(index.html):

```
<body>
  <a href="https://google1.co.il">google</a>
  <img src="https://www.leoweekly.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Modern_DSA.jpg" alt="">
  <a href="https://google2.co.il">google</a>
  <a href="https://google3.co.il">google</a>
</body>
```

index.php

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
$html = 'index.html';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile($html);
$array = array();

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
    array_push($array, $link->attributes->getNamedItem("href")->value);
}
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {
    array_push($array, $img->attributes->getNamedItem("src")->value);
}
?>
```

array:

```
Array ( [0] => https://google1.co.il 
        [1] => https://google2.co.il 
        [2] => https://google3.co.il 
        [3] => https://www.leoweekly.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Modern_DSA.jpg 
)
```

i would like to know how can i make post method with the best solution

> 1. with loop that send each index per request

or

> 2.all of them at the same time

*note:
Actually it's a mission that i need to run this on google snippet, it's need to work on Google chrome from in snippets this is mean i need to make this from server only(without access to client), there is way to make it from server ?

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify()` and post the resulting string from the client-side. On the server-side, use `json_decode()` to get at the values with the 2nd param set to `true`.

Comment: Actually it's a mission that i need to run this on google snippet, it's need to work on Google chrome from in snippets this is mean i need to make this from server only(without access to client), there is way to make it from server ?

Comment: A server can post another server, sure. But why do you have that html form in there?

Comment: with no reason sir, how can i make this post without form ? to insert the json_decode() to post req.body something like that: $_POST['json_decode()']

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use json_encode() for store array in json format and for get data use json_decode.    
<?php
    $html = 'index.html';
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTMLFile($html);
    $array = array();
    
    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
        array_push($array, $link->attributes->getNamedItem("href")->value);
    }
    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {
        array_push($array, $img->attributes->getNamedItem("src")->value);
    }
    $json_array = json_encode($array)
    ?>
```

Comment: how can i insert $json_array to input value ? or there is any way to made post without form submit?

Comment: No. just use $json_array variable to store array in database table.

Comment: Basically i have to made it on PHP local server

Comment: you can if it cant help you let me know

Comment: there is chance can you write me what exactly i need to code to make a post with $json_array value on PHP local server

Comment: do you know how to post data in table?

Comment: do you mean like this ?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11167870/17948018

Comment: you can do this pass variable in POST $_POST[$json_array];

Comment: i made this:  $_POST[$json_array]; and i get error as Notice: Undefined index

Comment: do you copy all my code above and pass the correct avariable in POST?

Comment: Yes you can see here [link](https://ibb.co/6DGYrPz)